# Display relevant headers for login-protected part of the site (strange Devise error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Much of my site is members-only. This has the disadvantage that when members exchange links with each other, e.g. on the official Facebook group, the preview will only show the generic "My Site", without any hint of which part of the site they linked to. That is because the Facebook crawler (or any other crawler) will hit the Login form and not see beyond.

In order to have a more relevant preview, I need to set the page's title as a function of the page beyond the login page. I have found that Devise has a neat method for this called `after_sign_in_path_for(User)`, so I thought to do a switch based on the return value of this method...

... and suddenly nobody got redirected after login anymore. Turns out that `after_sign_in_path_for(User)` erases its own data when you call it, so you cannot use it in order to figure out the page title and still redirect people after login.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found, after studying the innards of Devise, is to use `session["user_return_to"]`. This is where Devise gets the after-login path from if you haven't redefined it. You can retrieve the value, but whenever `after_sign_in_path_for(User)` is called the value is destroyed.